# SQLite; Is there a parameter to rewrite a single record each time

Tags: c#, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

Right now, I can write records one by another, as it's shown below.
How do I rewrite a single record each time? For example only first one.

[image]

**Code Behind:**

```
 public static List<PersonModel> LoadPeople()
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {                
            var output = cnn.Query<PersonModel>("select * from Person", new DynamicParameters());
            return output.ToList();
        }
    }

    public static void SavePerson(PersonModel person)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            cnn.Execute("insert into Person (FirstName, LastName) values (@FirstName, @LastName)", person);

        }
    }

    private static string LoadConnectionString(string id = "Default")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the first row (id=1), you can go to the Execute SQL tab and use this:

```sql
UPDATE Person SET FirstName=Mitsubishi WHERE Id=1;
```

In your c# code I guess it would be:

```cs
public static void UdatePerson(PersonModel person, int id)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            cnn.Execute("update Person (FirstName, LastName) set (@FirstName, @LastName) where Id = @id", new {person, id});
        }
    }
```

Take a look at that link if you need further information: https://dapper-tutorial.net/execute

Comment: How is it going to look for C#?

Comment: I think you are not showing/telling us everything, if you have some c# code behind and you want to update that row from c#, then you should probably show us some of that code so we can help you

Comment: I've added code behind.

Comment: I have also updated my answer.

Comment: At the end of the string 'id' causes a mistake, sounds like: The name 'id' doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: how do I use this method, fro example in button even? Can't use that.